# How does Rails load model_name.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I'm having a problem where my model_name.js file isn't getting loaded for some reason.  However, I tend to remove require_tree . from application.js because this application has a lot of varying js and I don't want it all included by default.

Does removing require_tree mean my model_name.js doesn't get loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, removing `//= require_tree .` will not include the files under `app/assets/javascripts`. You can include it manually by adding `//= require model_name` on your `application.js`

Comment: Are you sure Rails doesn't include each model name's js files? Every controller and view and js of a model name is all connected I thought.

Comment: It doesn't if you remove `//= require_tree .`, since that line includes every file on `app/assets/javascripts`

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly require the file in application.js as //= require 'file_name'.